# Unable to run Google Dot Net API Client Sample

Tags: .net, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to play around with the new client libraries for Google API:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

I've downloaded and extracted the sample code:
[Google API Dotnet Client Sample Solution](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.1/Generated/ZipFiles/google-api-dotnet-client-1.8.1.samples.zip)

I've also setup the necessary API access in:
[Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

But for some reason, I simply cannot get anything to start properly.

As I know there are a lot of samples in the Sample Solution posted above, I'll try to narrow it down first to making just one of the projects run, Plus.ServiceAccount.

After creating a Service Account in the Developer Console and downloading the P12 JSON key, and replacing the one in the project, I am running into the error:

CryptographicException was unhandled (The system cannot find the file specified.)

And the error happens at this line:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I hope someone could provide some kind of a very straightforward example to get things running quickly. I am finding the Google Documentation on using the Client Libraries lacking and inadequate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be that it can't find your key. Try using Server.MapPath

```
Server.MapPath("path to key")
```

or

Store the path to you key file in a variable and pass that as an argument

```
 string key_file = @"path to key";
```